# Mount external drive from command line just like in GUI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, permissions, mount

When I connect my 3 TB drive to my laptop (running Kubuntu 14.04), I can see it with `fdisk -l` and can mount it with `mount` as root, but I end up seeing all the files as `root:root` with strange permissions.

If I go into my laptop and connect the drive with the popup, I see the drive in `media` and all the folders / files have proper permissions.

If I want to mount this drive from the command line and have it retain those permissions and be found in `/media`, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /media/drive
```

It should mount the device **/dev/sda1** in **/media/drive** with read-write permissions for everyone.

You can also give permissions for already mounted devices:

```
chmod o+w /media/drive
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using udisks:

> # sudo udisks --mount /dev/

This mounts the drive the same way as KDE would do, so it should also appear in the file manager and also make it possible to dismount it from there.